# Is this blue one called 'threshold? Or 'runway threshold bar?'

Tags: airport, faa

Is this blue one called 'threshold? Or 'runway threshold bar?' in FAA?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

AIM 2-3-3-j refers to this painted stripe as a “Runway Threshold Bar” In the paragraph heading, and then refers to it simply as “a threshold bar” in the paragraph.  Quoting directly from the AIM:

***j. Runway Threshold Bar.**  A threshold bar delineates the beginning of the runway that is available for landing when the threshold has been relocated or displaced.*